# Write a program to divide the string into token and print it in C

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char token[20][256];
    char input[256];
    char *ctmp;
    int i = 1, cnt = 1;
    printf("$");
    scanf("%s", input);
    ctmp = strtok(input, " ");
    while (ctmp != NULL) {
        strcpy(token[cnt++], ctmp);
        ctmp = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    while (i < cnt) {
        printf("%s\n", token[i]);
        i++;
        system("pause");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to write a program which can divide " " from sentences into token.
But it just work on 1st word but not a second word..

Why it is so? am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` reads in until a white space, so you should use `fgets` which reads until the end of the line (or EOF, whichever occurs first), so it should be:

```
  fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
```

(for more details check out http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

The line you read may also turn out to be longer than the buffer would be able to hold, so you might need an extra loop to get the whole line and either resize the buffer accordingly, or iteratively process the line chunk by chunk.

Comment: Suggest `fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)`

Answer (score 0):

int main() {

```
char *s;
s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
scanf("%[^\n]", s);
s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1); 
int lengths=strlen(s);
if(lengths<=1000&&lengths>=1){
    char *tokens=strtok(s," ");

while(tokens!=NULL){
    printf("%s\n",tokens);
    tokens=strtok(NULL," ");
}

}



return 0;
```

}